# Eclipse loads wrong drawable resources

Tags: android, eclipse, resources, load, drawable

I work on my project about 3 weeks. Everything worked fine until today. I copied a new .png photo in my `res/drawable` folder, and now, when I run the project I always get wrong resources in image view in every listview item. Like everything mixed up. I read IDs from integer array, for example: `final static int[] icons = new int[]{R.drawable.picture1, R.drawable.picure2};`. For each item in listview, image view display wrong icon, like it randomly takes from `drawable` folder. I don't get any warnings or errors in logcat. I tried cleaning and building, and some other solutions I found on this site, but nothing worked... Thanks!

Comment: Hard to tell, with so little elements... can you add some relevant code, tell us the name of the new picture file (let me guess: picture3.png)?

Comment: No, the names are on Croatian language, I just gave for example picture1, picture2, and so on, because you won't understand my names, I think. There are 15 icons in my drawable folder.

Comment: Make sure you don't use special characters which aren't recognized by Android. Valid characters for file names: `a...z` (small caps ONLY - I fear it's limited to ENGLISH characters only), `0...9`, `.`, `_`

Comment: You said you copied it into res/drawable, but did you also replace any of the other drawable images (e.g. drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi)?